# Whitelisting Websites on Kubuntu Hotspot

Tags: proxy, hot-spot

I'm trying to create a Wi-Fi hotspot on my Kubuntu laptop. I want to limit internet access to a specific list of websites for devices connected to the hotspot. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.